# Complex square root command

Tags: complex

Is there a simple complex square root command to compute the square root of 1+I and a+bI where a and b are real, or even compute that of x where x is complex? I'm looking for a simple solution where one doesn't need to write code while specifying if given parameters are real or complex.

Comment: `Sqrt[z]` takes the complex square root. `ComplexExpand[Sqrt[1 + I]]` expands it into standard form.  Sometimes you might need to use the `TargetFunctions` option of `ComplexExpand`. See the docs.

Comment: I really don' t know who is thinking, that complex algebra can be learned from the the help files. Even the most experienced mathematicians, I know, have problems with the Mathematica ignorant Simplify strategies in producing readable real expressions from complex procedures. The many dayly mistakes coming up, are deonstrating, that there is something to be refomulated in the very heart of the complex algebra in most CAS of today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Moivre formula

$$ x  + I y = e^r \ (\cos \phi + i \sin \phi) ==
                 \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}  \ \ (\cosh + \sinh)\left[\frac{1}{2} \log{\frac{x+i y}{x-I y}}\right]$$

holds in the complex plane, with a cut along the negative real axis.

The square root takes the square root of the positive radius multiplied  by $\cos + i \sin$ of the half angle against the positive real axis.

So the square root maps the complex plane to the right half plane $\Re z > 0$.

Define it by explicitely conjugating complex number atoms like

```
I == Complex[0,1]  :> Complex[0,-1] 

RealExpand[x_^(n_?Positive)] := 
    (  { #1 Cosh[#2] +  #1 * Sinh[#2]} &) @@
      ({(#1*#2)^(n/2), n/2 Log[#1/#2]} &) @@ 
       { x,  x /. {Complex[a_, b_] :> a - I b}}
```

Now we can do

```
        RealExpand[Sqrt[(1  +  I  )]]    
           {2^(1/4) Cos[\[Pi]/8]+I 2^(1/4) Sin[\[Pi]/8]}
```

Better dont use it, if symbols are not assumded to be real. But you can expand the procedure by conjugating everything like ComplexExpand does. I never use it because its nearly impossible to get rid of all the Conjugate, Re, Ims, Abs and Args.

Be careful with

```
    Complex[a,b]
```

One can play with these expressions,  but of course, mathematically, its not defined with entities a,b that are not real. For numbers, it works, by expanding the second argument with a factor I. In general, Mathematica algorithms play hard ball

```
   D[Complex[a[x]+ I b[x], c[x] + I d[x]],x]
```

$$  \left(a'(x)+i b'(x)\right) \mathbb{C}^{(1,0)}(a(x)+i b(x),c(x)+i d(x))+\left(c'(x)+i d'(x)\right) \mathbb{C}^{(0,1)}(a(x)+i b(x),c(x)+i d(x))$$
$$==a'(x)+i b'(x)+i \left(c'(x)+i d'(x)\right) $$

So, as expected, we have this funny, but consistent rule

DC = { Complex^{(1,0)} :> (1&), Complex^{(0,1)} :> (Complex[0,1]&) }

"Consistent" meaning the primitive algebraic kernel of D[_,x], as teached in high school analysis over the  field of integers: take the sum over all positions of x and replace it there by 1. 3 x counts as x+x+x. The fact, that saved Newton's reputation as a mathematician, perhaps his neck as a philosopher against the church: that the rule works even for integer and rational powers.